# VB.NET: Get Full name from AD

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, ldap

I am trying to get the full name of a user given their user id "domain\usarname". Tried a couple of different examples, but none seem to work.
I am using Visual Basic .Net 2010.

I had originally found the following code in VBS and ported to VBA and worked nicely. If I try to use the same code in VB.NET 2010 I get multiple errors and the LDAP path not found, even if I enter it manually.

```
Function FindUser()
 On Error GoTo Err

 Dim objRoot As Variant
 Dim LDAPdomainName As String
 Dim UserName As String
 Dim UserDomain As String

 Dim cn As Variant
 Dim cmd As Variant
 Dim rs As Variant


UserName = VBA.Environ("UserName") ' Gets Current User
UserDomain = VBA.Environ("UserDomain") 'Gets Current User's Domain


Set objRoot = GetObject("LDAP://RootDSE")
Domain= objRoot.Get("defaultNamingContext") 



 Set cn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
 Set cmd = CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
 Set rs = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

 cn.Open "Provider=ADsDSOObject;"

 cmd.activeconnection = cn
 'cmd.commandtext = "SELECT ADsPath FROM 'LDAP://" & Domain & "' WHERE sAMAccountName = '" & UserName & "'"
 'To see all attributes names available, connect with Active Directory Explorer and add to Select.
 cmd.commandtext = "SELECT cn, mail  FROM 'LDAP://" & Domain & "' WHERE sAMAccountName = '" & UserName & "'"
 Set rs = cmd.Execute


 Do Until rs.EOF
    Debug.Print rs("cn") & " E-mail: " & rs("mail")
    rs.MoveNext
 Loop


Exit_Err:
 If Not rs Is Nothing Then rs.Close
 If Not cn Is Nothing Then cn.Close
 Set rs = Nothing
 Set cmd = Nothing
 Set cn = Nothing
 Exit Function

Err:
 If Err <> 0 Then
    MsgBox "Error connecting to Active Directory Database: " & Err.Description
 Else
    If Not rs.BOF And Not rs.EOF Then
        rs.MoveFirst
        MsgBox rs(0)
    Else
        MsgBox "Not Found"
    End If
 End If
 Resume Exit_Err


End Function
```

Comment: what did you try so far ? You should add some code you have tested so far, so we don't propose something you have already explored.

Comment: Well, what he has tried hasn't worked, so anything that works is a valid proposal.

Answer (score 3):

If you're on .NET 3.5 and up, you should check out the `System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement` (S.DS.AM) namespace. Read all about it here:

- [Managing Directory Security Principals in the .NET Framework 3.5](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc135979.aspx)
- [MSDN docs on System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.accountmanagement.aspx)

Basically, you can define a domain context and easily find users and/or groups in AD:

```
' set up domain context
Dim ctx As New PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain)

' find a user
Dim user As UserPrincipal = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(ctx, "domain\username")

' do something here....     
If user IsNot Nothing Then
End If

' find the group in question
Dim group As GroupPrincipal = GroupPrincipal.FindByIdentity(ctx, "YourGroupNameHere")

' if found....
If group IsNot Nothing Then
    ' iterate over members
    For Each p As Principal In group.GetMembers()
            ' do whatever you need to do to those members
        Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", p.StructuralObjectClass, p.DisplayName)
    Next
End If
```

The new S.DS.AM makes it really easy to play around with users and groups in AD!

Comment: On ctx As New PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain) I am getting a Ldap Exception was unhandled error message: "The connection cannot be established."

Answer (score 3):

What about:

> Imports System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement
>
> Dim userFullName As String = UserPrincipal.Current.DisplayName

Answer (score 1):

I have 2 functions which have helped me do this from .Net 2.0 all the way to .Net 4.0
after having a quick glance at MSDN this *should* work in all versions of the .Net runtimes.

The 2 functions are:

---

```
'Determines your domain name
Private Function DomainName() As String
    Dim objRootDSE As New System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry("LDAP://RootDSE")
    DomainName = objRootDSE.Properties("defaultNamingContext")(0)
End Function

'Will output user first name and last name. 
Public Sub ReturnUserName(ByVal UserAccountName As String)
    ' add a reference to System.DirectoryServices.dll
    Dim srch As System.DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher
    Dim result As System.DirectoryServices.SearchResult
    Dim de, dir As System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry

    de = New System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry("LDAP://" & DomainName())
    srch = New System.DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher(de)

    srch.SearchScope = SearchScope.Subtree
    srch.PropertiesToLoad.Add("givenName")
    srch.PropertiesToLoad.Add("sn")

    'Other field examples:
    'srch.PropertiesToLoad.Add("distinguishedName")
    'srch.PropertiesToLoad.Add("uid")

    ' users require both "user" and "person" filters
    ' and we also add the sAMAccountName to get the user passed.
    ' If you want to return all users in the domain remove the (sAMAccountName=" & UserAccountName & ")
    ' from the filter below.
    srch.Filter = "(&(objectClass=user)(objectCategory=person)(sAMAccountName=" & UserAccountName & "))"

    For Each result In srch.FindAll()
        dir = result.GetDirectoryEntry
        ' Properties are case sensitive!
        Debug.WriteLine(dir.Properties("givenname").Value & " " & dir.Properties("cn").Value)
    Next
End Sub
```

---

An example call to this would be:

---

```
Public Sub TestUserCall()
    'Returns the current logged in user.
    Call ReturnUserName(System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent.Name)
End Sub
```

---

This example call will work in runtime versions 2.0 to 4.0 for sure and again *should* work in all versions released so far.

The related MSDN pages are:

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.principal.windowsidentity.name(v=VS.100).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.principal.windowsidentity.name%28v=VS.100%29.aspx)

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/94se97ay(v=VS.80).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/94se97ay%28v=VS.80%29.aspx)

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.directoryservices.directoryentry(v=VS.80).aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.directoryservices.searchresult(v=VS.80).aspx

Comment: On the line "DomainName = objRootDSE.Properties("defaultNamingContext")(0)" I am getting a COMException was unhandled error: "The network path was not found."

Comment: I can only think for some reason your machine may not be returning the domain server. Please try replacing "LDAP://RootDSE" with "LDAP://server.com/RootDSE" server.com being the DNS of your domain server.

Comment: That should be replace the first line in the DomainName() sub to Dim objRootDSE As New System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry("LDAP://server.com/RootDSE") server.com being the DNS of your domain server.

Comment: Tried changing to all the different DNS servers on the network, with the full hostname, and even IP address, but still get the same error.

Comment: What version OS is your domain controller running? Am I right in suspecting Windows Server 2003?

Comment: Just noticed you are trying to look at the DNS server(s). You need to point it at your domain controller server, you can can find the address by opening a command prompt and typing "set logonserver" this should give you the UNC name of the DC and put that in place of the server.com in the string without the "\\"

Comment: I was pointing at the main domain controller which runs on Windows Server 2008.

Comment: never come across this before, during my searching no one seems to give answer as to why this could happen. only other post that offers  an answer is sadly a rather depressing answer: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/netfxnetcom/thread/6c606c8d-1c71-4d95-93a3-cb4b5b507f7a

Answer (score 0):

You can use [System.DirectoryServices](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180885.aspx) namespace to perform this kind of a task (DirectoryServices is a managed wrapper for LDAP).

```
Try
   ' Bind to the users container.
    Dim entry As New 
          DirectoryEntry("LDAP://CN=users,DC=fabrikam,DC=com")

    ' Create a DirectorySearcher object.
    Dim mySearcher As New DirectorySearcher(entry)

    ' Create a SearchResultCollection object to hold a collection
    ' of SearchResults returned by the FindAll method.
    Dim result As SearchResultCollection = mySearcher.FindAll()

    ' Create an object to hold a single result from the 
    ' result collection.
    Dim resEnt1 As SearchResult

    ' Get search results. For more information, 
    ' see Getting Search Results.
    ' 
    ' This sample uses Try...Catch to catch errors.
    ' Create an Exception object. For more information, 
    ' see System.Exception.

Catch Exception1 As System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException
    Console.WriteLine(Exception1.Message)

Catch Exception2 As InvalidOperationException
    Console.WriteLine(Exception2.Message)

Catch Exception3 As NotSupportedException
    Console.WriteLine(Exception3.Message)

End Try
```

You can use a [search string](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/323ez5ab.aspx) such as `"(&(objectCategory=user)(objectClass=person)(sAMAccountName=" + userId + "))"` to [search for a user](http://www.eggheadcafe.com/articles/20051106.asp) (userID would need to be replaced with the User's ID).

To tie it all together you can modify the snippet below to pull back [all of the properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180881%28v=VS.90%29.aspx) for a user. You can then adjust it to only focus on the User Name.

```
Dim results As SearchResultCollection = Nothing

Try
    ' Bind to the users container.
    Dim path As String = "LDAP://CN=users,DC=fabrikam,DC=com"
    path = "LDAP://CN=Users,DC=strohmadom,DC=nttest,DC=microsoft,DC=com"
    Dim entry As New DirectoryEntry(path)

    ' Create a DirectorySearcher object.
    Dim mySearcher As New DirectorySearcher(entry)

    ' Set a filter for users with the name test.
    mySearcher.Filter = "(&(objectClass=user)(anr=test*))"

    ' Use the FindAll method to return objects to a SearchResultCollection.
    results = mySearcher.FindAll()

    ' Iterate through each SearchResult in the SearchResultCollection.
    Dim searchResult As SearchResult
    For Each searchResult In results
        ' Display the path of the object found.
        Console.WriteLine("Search properties for {0}", _
            searchResult.Path)

        ' Iterate through each property name in each SearchResult.
        Dim propertyKey As String
        For Each propertyKey In searchResult.Properties.PropertyNames
            ' Retrieve the value assigned to that property name 
            ' in the ResultPropertyValueCollection.
            Dim valueCollection As ResultPropertyValueCollection = searchResult.Properties(propertyKey)

            ' Iterate through values for each property name in each SearchResult.
            Dim propertyValue As Object
            For Each propertyValue In valueCollection
                ' Handle results. Be aware that the following 
                ' WriteLine() only returns readable results for 
                ' properties that are strings.
                Console.WriteLine("{0}:{1}", _
                    propertyKey, _
                    propertyValue.ToString())
            Next propertyValue
        Next propertyKey
    Next searchResult
Finally
    ' To prevent memory leaks, always call 
    ' SearchResultCollection.Dispose() manually.
    If Not results Is Nothing Then
        results.Dispose()
        results = Nothing
    End If
End Try
```

Comment: On the line "results = mySearcher.FindAll()" I am getting the error that the "The network path was not found.". I substituted the LDAP path string to our LDAP server.

Answer (score 0):

Easy way with Excel:

```html
Dim xls As New Excel.Application
U_Name = xls.Application.UserName
xls.Quit()
```